# Meteor error message client-side

Tags: node.js, meteor, client

I'm using the framework [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) (Node.js).

I get this error message in my web browser when my project page is loaded:

> The connection to ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/622/u2zaukpp/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.

Why is it occuring?

Comment: Without any context that is probably impossible to say. You will have to show some code.

Comment: Actually, the "Meteor" tag provides enough context to answer. It would be better specified in the question itself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens every single time you reload the page or it gets reloaded by the server.

Basically the page is constantly receiving data from the server (collections data, methods, or simply a ping). Since it is constantly open and Meteor forces a reload on code change (or you did force one by reloading the page), your browser freaks out and shows you this error.
It can also happen if the Meteor process is killed.

Thus, expect to see this error **a lot** during development, you don't have to worry about it.